# Symfony5: How do I make API routes accessible without login?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony5.4

In `security.yml` I have defined below:

```
 access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/getDays, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }        
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

But `http://localhost:8000/api/search.json` always redirects to login page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a route matches the pattern, the system halts the process and does not proceed further. So, your `access_control` applies the third line. Switch line 3 and 4, and it should work:

```yaml
 access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/getDays, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }        
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**Source: [How Does the Security access_control Work?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)**

> For each incoming request, Symfony checks each access_control entry to find one that matches the current request. As soon as it finds a matching access_control entry, it stops - only the first matching access_control is used to enforce access.